# Spring social authentication behind nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, spring-social

Spring social adds wrong *Location* header when authenticating behind proxy

My setup consists of 3 docker images

- Nginx
- Spring boot application
- Angular 5 application

Now when authenticating everything works fine until google authentication succeeds.

When google redirect to my page the request url is correct *https://example.com/signin/google*, but the *Location* header is *http://backend-app:8080/social/signup* and the browser tries to access the url in location header which fails because it's an internal url.

In configuration I set *https://example.com* as the application url

```
@Bean
public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, SignInAdapter signInAdapter) {
    ProviderSignInController providerSignInController = new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, signInAdapter);
    providerSignInController.setSignUpUrl("/social/signup");
    providerSignInController.setApplicationUrl(environment.getProperty("application.be.url"));
    return providerSignInController;
}
```

But somehow the *Location* header is still the internal url. I'm not sure whether the issue is in nginx or back-end application, but I suspect the back-end application.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by adding to my nginx.

```
location /signin {
    proxy_set_header Host example.com;
    proxy_pass http://backend-app:8080/signin;
}

location /social {
    proxy_set_header Host example.com;
    proxy_pass http://backend-app:8080/social;
}
```

I tried that previously, but maybe I did something else wrong then...